# Clockify API & Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, clockify

I have been done the rabbit role for the last day trying to connect to the clockify API using Power Bi. (My experience with API's is minimal).

Any help to put my in the right direction would be appreciated

I'm assuming out of all my attempts this is the most correct approach.

```
= let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.clockify.me/api/", [Headers=[Accept="application/json", Authorization="X-api-key xxxxxxxxxxxx"]])),
    messages = Source[messages]
in 
    Source
```

I keep getting this error:

> Expression.Error: The 'Authorization' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Referer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You authorization header seems to be wrong. Instead of using:

Authorization="X-api-key xxxxxxxxxxxx"

use:

X-api-key="xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: Thanks for this, when trying this I get a syntax error :(

Comment: Expression.SyntaxError: Invalid identifier.      The error is referring to the X in X-api-key

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let
   Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.clockify.me/api/", 
   [Headers=[Accept="application/json", #"x-api-key"="xxxxxxxxxx"]])),
   messages = Source[messages]
in 
   Source
```

Comment: I tried this and I get,  Expression. Error: The 'x-api-key' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Referer  'code'

Comment: I do not get this error. Is the credential-type set to anonymous? You can edit this by using [Data Source Settings] (home-tab), select the clockify connection, edit permissions, edit credential type.

Comment: Just switch credentials and its not giving me any errors, :D. But theres no data do I need to edit the URL?

Comment: I don't now. I also did not get any data, but I presumed that was because you used another key in stead of "xxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: So I replaced xxxxxxxx with my Key and it didn't return anything. Could I create a test account in Clockify for us to use?